# Scrapy Splash recursive crawl not working

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I tried to use tips from similar questions but did not come to success.
In the end, I returned to the starting point and I want to ask your help.

I cant execute a recursive crawl process with scrapy splash, but do it without problems on a single page. I see issue in bad urls to scrape:

```
2019-04-16 16:17:11 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to '192.168.0.104': <GET http://192.168.0.104:8050/************>
```

But link must be `https://www.someurl.com/***************`

```
def start_requests(self):
    for url in self.start_urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse, meta={'splash': {'endpoint': 'render.html', 'args': {'wait': 0.5}}})

def parse(self, response):
    ***********
    items_urls = ***********
    for url in items_urls.extract():
        yield Request(urlparse.urljoin(response.url, url), callback=self.parse_items, meta={'item': item})

def parse_items(self, response):
    ***********
    yield item
```

Comment: You probably have the attribute "allowed_domains" configured on your spider and are trying to request an url from outside this domain. Try removing a line similar to this and run the spider again: allowed_domains = ['example.com']

Comment: @LuizRodriguesdaSilva all pages on some domain. I think in this situation i need a slightly tune Splash Request, but i don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution:

Just remove a `urlparse.urljoin(response.url, url)` module and change it to simple string like a `"someurl.com" + url`

Now all links are correct and a crawl process works fine.

But now I have a some troubles with crawl loops, but its another question :)